# Can custom entry sources have their own URLs?

Tags: control-panel, sources

I can go to http://example.com/admin/entries/sectionHandle, and the Entries list has that source selected, but I can't find a way to do that with sources added through [modifyEntrySources](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntrySources).

I've got two extra sources for entries that have been fully translated, and those that haven't, so we can track our progress as we translate the site.

Is there anything I can add to the array so that I could link to something like http://www.example.com/admin/entries/untranslated?

```
public function modifyEntrySources(&$sources, $context)
{
    if ($context == 'index')
    {
        $sources[] = array('heading' => 'Translations');

        $sources['translations:untranslated'] = array(
            'label' => Craft::t('Untranslated'),
            'criteria' => array('translationCompleted' => array('0', null))
        );

        $sources['translations:translated'] = array(
            'label' => Craft::t('Translated'),
            'criteria' => array('translationCompleted' => '1')
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little more digging, I discovered this can be achieved by adding a `data` array with a `handle` value to the source, so that code becomes:

```
public function modifyEntrySources(&$sources, $context)
{
    if ($context == 'index')
    {
        $sources[] = array('heading' => 'Translations');

        $sources['translations:untranslated'] = array(
            'label'    => Craft::t('Untranslated'),
            'criteria' => array('translationCompleted' => array('0', null)),
            'data'     => array('handle' => 'untranslated'),
        );

        $sources['translations:translated'] = array(
            'label'    => Craft::t('Translated'),
            'criteria' => array('translationCompleted' => '1'),
            'data'     => array('handle' => 'translated'),
        );
    }
}
```

This doesn't appear to work for nested sources however.